# MongoDB - Do subdocuments count towards the total size of a document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm wondering if you had something like a `list` and a subdocument of `items`. Does MongoDB save them all as a single document, or does MongoDB regard the subdocuments as independent documents. This is in regard to the 16mb document limit.

E.g.

list document:

```
{
  items: [
    {
      _id: 1
      name: "item1"
    }
    {
      _id: 2
      name: "item2"
    }
    {
      _id: 3
      name: "item3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `Does MongoDB save them all as a single document,` Yes.

Comment: @Laiv thanks, then my change of approach will not have been for nothing

Comment: @Laiv can you provide any reference for this claim ? Because several sources claim that nested documents zre taken into account. Fir example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19401813/3723423

Comment: @Christophe I'm agreeing with you. Nested documents are taken into account regarding the document total size, because at the end, for mongo there's no such thing as "subdocument" or "nested document". It's a single document. Unless you use DBRef, but these are addressed to provide support to a handful MongoDB drivers. To these cases, the size of the referenced document is not taken into account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDb [manages json documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-document) in a binary [bson](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) format.  In particular, bson is used to [store documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) in the database and exchange the documents with the outside world.

Document with embedded/nested documents will be stored in a bson object that contains all its elements, including the nested ones. There is no automatic disassembling and reassembling. In fact, all the access to the nested documents will go through the owning document.

The [16 MB limit is meant to](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents) facilitate the management of documents in memory and in remote function calls. It therefore applies to the whole bson document including all its nested elements. There's by the way a limit of 100 to the nested depth.

More information:

- [Beware of MongoDb's document size limits](http://renderedtext.com/blog/2012/02/17/beware-of-mongodbs-document-size-limit/) (blog)
- [Model Relationships Between Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/) (mogodb doc) compare embedded documents with references
- [Database model design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/) (mongodb doc): compare the normalized approach (references) with the embedded approach - **confirms that document size limit has to be considered for the embedded approach**
- [Collections and embedded documents in MongoDb](https://fosterelli.co/collections-and-embedded-documents-in-mongodb) (blog): about when to use embedded documents or different collection
- [answer to an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19401813/3723423) about general document limits but which specifically addresses embedded documents